# Computational complexity - Quantum system

Tags: quantum-mechanics, computational-physics, software, algorithms

I have created a genetic algorithm to solve for the ground state of an arbitrary Hermitian matrix. it does this by working out fitness values which i have defined as -E = -$<\psi|\hat{H}|\psi>$. so that fitness increases as energy decreases. I have worked out the eigenvalues using MATLAB, and can get extremely close to the ground state energy, and in doing so produce candidate state vectors that are within 1% of other eigenvalues.

I'm trying to work out the complexity $\mathcal{O}$ to calculate the energy of a quantum system using the expectation value,

$$<\psi|\hat{H}|\psi>$$

which is matrix multiplication with a vector, then vector-vector multiplication.
Can I model this as $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ as $\hat{H}$ is $n\times n$ and each vector is $n\times 1$?

in comparison to methods used to diagonalise a hermitian matrix such as Lanczos method, which i believe to be of complexity $\mathcal{O}(m^3)$.

I have been researching this, but unable to find an answer, and i do not know where to start.

Comment: Complexity is a characteristic of an algorithm, but "Compute $\langle \psi\vert H\vert \psi\rangle$" is not an algorithm, it's a goal that several specific algorithms can fulfill is specific situations. I therefore don't understand what you're asking for.

Comment: you need to provide additional information.  Are you looking for just one average value of a random state?

Comment: I have edited my original post. Hope that makes it clearer?

Comment: You may take a look at [this article](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/62904/complexity-of-eigenvalue-decomposition) and the links there.

Comment: Your algorithm clearly takes $O(n^3)$ per lookup. But note that if the system has $d$ particles, generically $n$ is some exponential function of $d$.

Comment: thanks @JahanClaes I thought as much, Is my complexity for solving for eigenvalues using diagonalisation methods correct? i.e. $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$?

Comment: If $n$ is the size of the matrix, what is $m$?  How can candidate vectors (note: plural when the OP is looking for the unique ground state) be close to other eigenvalues?  Do you mean your candidate vector has 99% overlap with the true ground state?  Do you mean all each of your candidate eigenvectors have 99% overlaps with a corresponding exact eigenvectors?